# Why prophet Ibrahim a.s mentioned many time in Quran

Tags: prophet-ibrahim, seerah

I just couldn't wrap it in my head when we have to send salaam (salawat) to prophet Ibrahim (and what is the real intention of doing that?). And in Al-Quran there are so many time mention about him.

> And [mention] when Abraham was raising the foundations of the House and [with him] Ishmael, [saying], "Our Lord, accept [this] from us. Indeed You are the Hearing, the Knowing. **Al-Baqarah:127**

---

> And Abraham instructed his sons [to do the same] and [so did] Jacob,
>   [saying], "O my sons, indeed Allah has chosen for you this religion,
>   so do not die except while you are Muslims." **Al-Baqarah:132**

---

> Have you not considered the one who argued with Abraham about his Lord [merely] because Allah had given him kingship? When Abraham said, "My Lord is the one who gives life and causes death," he said, "I give life and cause death." Abraham said, "Indeed, Allah brings up the sun from the east, so bring it up from the west." So the disbeliever was overwhelmed [by astonishment], and Allah does not guide the wrongdoing people. **Al-Baqarah:258**

There are just too many about him in this holy book. I know him as *Khalilullah* but what is so special about him? Because Allah already declared Islam is the [favourable deen](https://quran.com/3/19) which is jihaded by our Prophet, Muhammad SAW.

Comment: There are many reasons the most important, is the claim that Ibraheem was a Muslim and we are following his millah beside other facts like the relationship to Arabs (via the offspring of Isma'el, the re-building of the Ka'aba etc. which come to mind.

Comment: Please also note that Prophet Musa was mentioned in the Qu'ran 135 times while Prophet Ibrahim was mentioned 67 times.

Comment: @Medi1Saif do you mean that other prophet of Israel people not muslim?

Comment: No that's not what I mean, but as his shari'a was earlier than the one of Moses one could say "he was the first".

Answer (score 2):

First, it should be made clear that comparing the number of times people are mentioned in the Quran doesn't necessarily show their status. For example, Yusuf (AS) was mentioned by name 27 times in the Quran and the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) was "only" mentioned by name 5 times. This, of course, does not show any superiority of Yusuf (AS) over Muhammad (SAW).

For the question of why Ibrahim (AS) was mentioned in the Quran so many times (169 to be precise), Allah explicitly says in the Quran:

> **There has already been for you an excellent example in Ibrahim** and those with him, when they said to their people, "Indeed, we are disassociated from you and from whatever you worship other than Allah. We have denied you, and there has appeared between us and you animosity and hatred forever until you believe in Allah alone" except for the saying of Abraham to his father, "I will surely ask forgiveness for you, but I have not [power to do] for you anything against Allah. Our Lord, upon You we have relied, and to You we have returned, and to You is the destination. (60:4)

In this verse, Allah mentions a specific instance of a good example, but the point is that Ibrahim (AS) was a great example for everyone after him. He was an extremely devout person who submitted to God and went against his own people at a very young age for Allah's cause.

In old age, he continued to show his complete submission to God by passing the many tests Allah gave him including one where he was asked to sacrifice and slaughter his own son. This is why Allah promised Ibrahim (AS):

> "Indeed, I will make you a leader (Imam) for the people." (2:214)

As part of that promise, Ibrahim (AS)'s stories, demonstrations of faith, and blessings are mentioned to us so that we follow his example since he is our Imam. Ibrahim (AS)'s example was so good that Allah said:

> And who would be averse to the religion of Abraham except one who makes a fool of himself. And We had chosen him in this world, and indeed he, in the Hereafter, will be among the righteous. (2:130)

Here are some things in our religion which come from Ibrahim (AS) directly or indirectly:

- The Holiness of Makkah: It is because of the dua of Ibrahim (AS) to make it so. See 2:126
- The Kaabah: He built the Kaabah which is our Qibla. See 2:127
- The Hajj and its rituals: See 22:27 and 2:128
- Eid ul-Adha: Comes from the sacrifice of Ismail (AS) commanded to Ibrahim (AS) which he fulfilled in his complete submission to God. Then, Allah replaced Ismail (AS) with an animal to sacrifice instead. See 37:102
- The Prophet Muhammad (SAW): He was the answer to a dua of Ibrahim (AS). See 2:129
- The countless other prophets from his progeny in Bani Israel: They were part of Allah's reward to him for his submission and patience. See 29:27

Comment: I would also mentioned that prophet Ibrahim(alayhis salaam) at very young age he believed in Allah Most High, he was a wise person.  Our Allah made him his friend that alone says alot about him, may Allah bless and raise his rank hereafter, ameen.

Answer (score -1):

Because He is one of the prophets who has a real high Place Before ALLAH 
As he has given the title Khalillulah (friend of ALLAH) 
& And he and his son Ismail were the one to build Kaba
& Also the reason that we celebrate Bakra-Eid when we ziba goats..
& Also that he had 2 Sons Hazarate Isaaq (alaihisalam) & Hazrate Ismail(alaihisalam) 
from Ismail(alaihisalam) our Nabi (Rasool) Hazarat Mohammad (Sallahualaihisalam) was born.
And from Hazarate Isaaq (alaihisalam) 
There were so many of Nabi and Rasul u cant count few of them that I know are
Hazarate Yakub,Yusuf,Musa,Haroon,Isa (alaihisalam)
And the Name of Hazarate Ibrahim(alaihisalam) comes in prayer Because 
that Durude Ibrahimi is Kind of Prayer that ya ALLAH Please give the same barkat and rehmat u gave to Hazarate Ibrahim's children (that one was given the our Prophet & the other Son was given so many other Prophets)
to our Prophet hazrat Mohammad (sallahualaihisalam)

and So many more reason that he is Important 
cant type them all and I dont even know them all but here is what I know,
Hope it helped
FIAMMANILLAH...!

Comment: Thanks @Frost. But my question is that, if Alquran is a message to all humankind, then if your refer to this [surah](https://quran.com/22/78), `[It is] the religion of your father, Abraham`. Does it sound that ayah only point to only and only Muhammad SAW? How about all people who are just not born Arab?

Comment: See,all of the ayats of Quran came only when needed curtain things happen so to restrict them or guide them they were given to Our Prophet so that he can guide us but,this particular ayat u are telling directly points to hazrat Muhammad(sallahulaihiwasalam) because he is his son directly and This Ayat also Points to the jews&christian whose believes came from hazrat Musa & Isa alaihisalam(moses&jesus as they say) which where sons of hazrat Isaaq alaihisalam which was again his son.All the ayat have a particular meaning to them and as this is to guide Jews&christian and to remind them of that.

Comment: And this ayat points to Muhammad Salalauhualaiwasalam as he is his father and in return telling us that we should follow it,As it is the rightfull path(it is a message to humankind if u see it properly)

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul yes all the prophets that ever came in to the world starting from Hazrat Adam,Nooh to our Prophet Muhammad Sallahulaihiwasalam are muslim they were sent to the world to guide the people to the right path but as u see,After the wisal of Hazrat Musa & Isa alaihiasalam they changed the holy books given to them (Toraid&Injeel) And kept changing the things that they found difficult to follow so the books now u see are not proper, but when Quran was given ALLAH promised that he will keep it safe from getting changed (he will protect it)so as u see one even single letter is changed.

Comment: any idea why we give salaam to prophet Ibrahim in the tahiyatul akheer?

Comment: because he is one of the greatest  prophets came to this world what is wrong in doing that ?? and ALLAH gets happy about the person who sends salaam on prophet

Comment: that is just too weak reason for me